# Palindrome Testing - how to make case insensitive?

Tags: java, recursion, palindrome

My code will test for a palindrome however if there is any punctuation, spaces, or letters not of the same case it returns false. Does anyone know how I can make my code ignore case and punctuation? Thanks!

```
public class PalindromeDetector
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a phrase you wish to " +
                           " test to discover if it it a palindrome: ");
        s = kb.nextLine();

        if (palTest(s))
        System.out.println("Your phrase is a palindrome!");
        else
        System.out.println("Your phrase is not a palindrome.");

    }

    /**
    The palTest method will determine whether or not
    a phrase is a palindrome.
    @param str The phrase which will be tested.
    @return True/False whether or not the phrase was a
            palindrome.
    */
    public static boolean palTest(String str)
    {

        char first = str.charAt(0);
        char last = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);

        if (str.length() <= 2)
            return true;
        else if (first != last)
            return false;
        else
            return palTest(str.substring(1, str.length()-1));
    }
}
```

Comment: is Pa,hhap palindrome?

Comment: Do you have to do this manually or can you use [StringBuilder#reverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse())? If so, you can: (1) Get the initial String (2) Remove all punctuation (3) Make the String `toLowerCase` (4) Add it to a `StringBuilder` (5) Save the reverse in another String and then (6) See if both Strings have the same value

Comment: You have bigger problems than just punctuation. Your code has multiple major bugs

Comment: I have to do it with recursion. What major bugs do you see? @ControlAltDel Sorry I'm fairly new to coding, this is only my second semester doing any type of coding. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Forget the multiple part - it was late in the day and I was going out of my mind :) but this line: `if (str.length() <= 2) return true;` is definitely not right. Try the case of string = "ab"

Answer (score 1):

If you are just testing, you could normalize the String before handing it to your function, as for example with

```
palTest(s.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).replaceAll("\\W",""))
```

`\W` is the regular expression character class of all non word characters - Definitions here: [Character classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes)

Answer (score 1):

What about using [StringBuilder#reverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse())?

```
String m = s.replaceAll("\\p{P}", "");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(m);
String reversed = sb.reverse().toString();

// By using equalsIgnoreCase, you ignore the case and don't need toLowerCase()
return m.equalsIgnoreCase(reversed);
```